# Trouble with xml in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse

My r.java is gone in Eclipse and I know its due to a mistake I have in my xml. I am new to this so I dont know whats wrong with the following coding myself, I'm mainly just following tutorials on the internet.Thanks to anyone that can help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main" />

-     <TextView
-         android:id="@+id/textView1"
-         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
-         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
-         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
-         android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
-
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/st"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Test"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/drinkcounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Unit Counter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/drinklist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Drink List" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/drinkdrivinglimit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Drink Driving Limits" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/datarecord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Data Records" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```